# Technic Firetruck 8289 with different wheels?

Tags: technic, piece-information, sets, wheel

I am a bit confused with the Technic firetruck set 8289. The photo on its box:

[image]

clearly shows it has the wheels 56145c02:

[image]

however, according to this photo from BrickLink

[image]

it has 6595c01:

[image]

In the parts inventory both wheels are listed, but the parts of 56145c02 are also shown as alternate parts.

My questions: Does this set have a "facelifted" variant? Is there an alternate box showing the set with the other wheels, or LEGO simply changed the content without changing the box?

Comment: Interesting! I think I spy another difference between the two photos: The cabinet door on the side — in front of the rear wheel — appears to a have different labeling scheme. And, if I squint hard at the low-res photos, I may be able to detect differences in the license plate number. Wondering if anyone else can verify these diffs or can see others.

Comment: I think the license plates are the same, however the sticker below the windscreen is different - in the box art and on the sticker sheets on BrickLink it's "Truck 4", while in the other photo it's "Fire and Rescue". That might make the lower photo a development "product shot" taken before the wheels and stickers were finalised?

Answer (score 3):

The instructions show and Brickset lists [4496197: Rim Wide W.Cross 30/20](https://brickset.com/parts/4496197/rim-wide-w-cross-30-20) as the wheel rim of choice, which fits with the release year of the Fire Truck (2006) and the manufacturing dates of the rims (2006-2013).

BrickLink's "preferred" [rim](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6595&idColor=1#T=C&C=1) was only manufactured up to 2006, which might explain why it lists the pictured rim as an Alternative part - as that would have been included in later runs of the set.